# TinyMCE <p> elements lose their style on save

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I have a form that uses TinyMCE as part of a form. In its configuration, I am currently applying a margin style to the `<p>` elements with:

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector : 'textarea',
        //some other attributes
        content_style: "p {margin: 0}",
    });
```

This works as desired as far as display in the TinyMCE window itself, however when I save the text into my database the margin styles do not exist inside of the `<p>` tag.

The resulting issue is that when I display the text on "other" pages I don't retain the desired margin style.

My Question: Is there a way of retaining the applied style tag as configured for TinyMCE?

I have tried the following attributes and none seem to work:

```
    extended_valid_elements : "p[style]" //didn't work
    inline_styles : true //didn't work
    valid_elements: "#p[style]" //didn't work
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm sure the answer is right in front of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that `content_style` does is add CSS to the HTML document's head while you are editing in TinyMCE.  It won't add any inline CSS to the actual HTML that you create.

If you pass any CSS into TinyMCE via `content_style` you should make the same CSS available when you render the content so the resulting visualization is the same.

EDIT (based on your comment):

You could use the TinyMCE APIs to add a class programmatically to a given element.  For example:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p'), 'myclass');
```

...as with my initial comment, this would then require the `myclass` class to exist in the CSS that you have in your page when the content is rendered.

Either way you still need some CSS in the rendered page that will apply the style you desire.

Comment: Got it, thanks Michael. Let me try this - can you append a class to an element in TinyMCE so that its saved inside of the element's tag on save?

Comment: Awesome. This helps tremendously. Thanks again! **+1 Vote**

Comment: If that solves the issue can you select this as the answer?  That will stop others from answering and help future searchers know this is solved.